# How to stop NetworkManager to put Ubuntu server to sleep?

Tags: network-manager, suspend

I have an Ubuntu server instance that enters sleep mode from time to time (on average every two months). By looking in the syslog file, I see that it is the networkManager that requests to put the host to sleep.

Here is the log entry:

```
Aug 24 11:33:28 home dbus-daemon[1108]: [session uid=108 pid=1108] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.Notifications' requested by ':1.12' (uid=108 pid=1145 comm="/usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon/unity-settings-daem" label="unconfined")
Aug 24 11:33:29 home org.freedesktop.Notifications[1108]: Unable to init server: Impossible de se connecter : Connexion refusée
Aug 24 11:33:29 home notify-osd[19718]: cannot open display: 
Aug 24 11:33:29 home dbus-daemon[1108]: [session uid=108 pid=1108] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.Notifications' failed: Process org.freedesktop.Notifications exited with status 1
Aug 24 11:33:29 home dbus-daemon[1108]: [session uid=108 pid=1108] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.Notifications' requested by ':1.12' (uid=108 pid=1145 comm="/usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon/unity-settings-daem" label="unconfined")
Aug 24 11:33:29 home NetworkManager[880]: <info>  [1598261609.2373] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Aug 24 11:33:29 home NetworkManager[880]: <info>  [1598261609.2382] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Aug 24 11:33:29 home whoopsie[21081]: [11:33:29] offline
Aug 24 11:33:29 home org.freedesktop.Notifications[1108]: Unable to init server: Impossible de se connecter : Connexion refusée
Aug 24 11:33:29 home notify-osd[19725]: cannot open display: 
Aug 24 11:33:29 home dbus-daemon[1108]: [session uid=108 pid=1108] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.Notifications' failed: Process org.freedesktop.Notifications exited with status 1
Aug 24 11:33:29 home systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Aug 24 11:33:29 home systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Aug 24 11:33:29 home kernel: [3268843.256198] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Aug 24 11:33:29 home systemd-sleep[19726]: Suspending system...
```

What is causing this ? Is this the consequence of a network problem or a configuration issue ?

EDIT: here is some additional info requested in the comment

```
$ sudo systemctl status suspend.target
[sudo] Mot de passe de meessen : 
● suspend.target - Suspend
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/suspend.target; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd.special(7)
```

Comment: Have you added a desktop? and thus turned your server into a desktop? (which will sleep)  You didn't provide release details which may have confirmed my suspicion.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo systemctl status suspend.target`?

Comment: The output indicates that NetworkManager was not the trigger of the sleep command. It *received* the sleep command along with other services. NM has a lot to do when a sleep command is received. The first log entry is that the command to sleep was received, and it's starting the process. The second log entry is that the process completed successfully, and NM is now asleep.

Comment: @guiverc I'm not sure, but I think I could have added desktop support to the server because I wanted to use x2go. It was some years ago. How could I check if this is the case ?

Comment: @starkus I have edited my question to add the output of the command

Comment: I don't know your release, however I see messages related to desktop in what you posted, inc. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=unity-settings  , let alone desktop notifications

Comment: @user535733 This makes sense. I can't see in syslog what triggered the sleep request. Do you have any suggestion to find that out ?

Comment: I found this web page describing how to disable sleep. https://www.unixtutorial.org/disable-sleep-on-ubuntu-server/ Should/Could I use it ?

Comment: "(on average every two months)"  there is no setting in the desktop nor in the server to do that. @chmike do you have a sleep target as told in the link? if so: go for it.

Comment: You could mask those services responsible for energy saving, like suspend and hibernate, as told in the link. I would give it a try. If you encounter any trouble you also may revert your changes, as told at the end of the link.

Comment: Look at the logs! `sudo journalctl --since="timestamp" --until="timestsmp"` read `man journalctl date`

Comment: @waltinator logs are the same as then one I found in syslog. It doesn't help

Answer (score 8):

Here is what works for me:

```
systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

This command disables the sleep mode on the server.

If we would like to enable it again:

```
systemctl unmask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```