# Stop ubuntu (20.04 AND 21.10) from shutting down automatically from lock screen?

Tags: shutdown, reboot, settings

Ubuntu is now auto shutting down after some period if I do not log in (hard wired keyboard) i.e. if I leave the desktop in the lock screen.

I do not yet understand why.

It does not shutdown if I log in.

I have also notices that it the screen sleep fails for a while now (while logged in).

I have it set to auto-reboot on power failure and want it to behave as a server.

Something has changed in settings. Going away now and want desktop to autoreboot on power failures (it does) but then it seems to shut down if I don't log in to the desk top. What could be triggering this? How to debug? What setting?

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

Screenshot from

last -x

isn't clear to me. [image]

I am running through various tests but one thing I am wondering is if the "root" settings are coming in to play when in the log in screen and how I can view those easily if so?

**UPDATE:**
This problem persists after update to

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:    21.10
Codename:   impish
```

Still looking for ideas. It would be good to understand what is non-default and start removing that. I will basically have to start from scratch with a clean install if this persists.

**UPDATE:**

This seems relevant [How to stop NetworkManager to put Ubuntu server to sleep?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271282/how-to-stop-networkmanager-to-put-ubuntu-server-to-sleep) as I see this in the /var/log/syslog before the shutdown occurs

```
NetworkManager[1239]: <info>  [1642455626.3604] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
```

See this: https://www.unixtutorial.org/disable-sleep-on-ubuntu-server/

Comment: Check Power settings: is you computer set to automatically suspend?

Comment: @vanadium no it is set to "off" i.e. no suspend automatically

Comment: @mathtick did you solve your problem? If so, what was the issue? I have a similar problem (automatic **reboot** from lock-screen). `journalctl -e -b -1` does not show any sign of fatal error. System hibernation/suspension is disabled.

Comment: I don't remember now. I think I had to give up. I have some note about turn on automatic login for a while.

Comment: And I have this in a note https://discourse.ubuntubudgie.org/t/lockscreen-not-working-after-update-to-21-10/5394/40

Comment: I'm on 22.04 now. And I *think* it's ok but not sure.