# Network card issues after reinstall of 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, firewall

PC with PCI Lan card and motherboard Lan had previously worked fine on 18.04 and 20.04, was upgraded to 22.04 but found application compatibility issues so reinstalled 20.04. Now the integral Lan is working fine and the PCI Lan shows in Network Manager etc, all configured fine and I can ping the Lan card IP address but cannot ping anything on network. Link status is up and I've tested the cable and switch (changed both and tested again). Cannot ping this PC from other PCs on network.
TCPdump shows traffic on that Lan port but cannot browse nor ping. It's like the port is receiving but cannot transmit which leads me to think it's a firewall/IPTables issue but I tried `sudo ufw disable` and this didn't resolve it.

I still don't know why this occurred but I've swapped the IP configuration over on the 2 Lan cards and swapped the patching and now both are working correctly.

Update - checked PC again and found the same network is again not allowing transmitting (TCPdump is showing traffic received), but this network is now connected to the other Lan card since I swapped them over. The only thing I can think of now is that as this is a secondary local network there is no gateway nor DNS, is Ubuntu turning off the port for this reason (possibly related to sleep mode)? Receive would perhaps be available for WoL?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sleep issue. I found this post [How to stop NetworkManager to put Ubuntu server to sleep?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271282/how-to-stop-networkmanager-to-put-ubuntu-server-to-sleep) which gave the method of masking the sleep messages and the PC has run overnight without losing network.
I can only assume that the Lan with gateway and DNS woke from sleep correctly (or possibly didn't go to sleep) but because the Lan I had issues with didn't have a gateway or DNS it never woke up.

I hope this post helps someone, if anyone has more insight that would be good.